# How to repair cat nails puncture in leather couch

Tags: adhesive, hole, hole-repair

My cat has sharp nails and the leather couch is filled with tiny nail punctures. How can I repair it?

Comment: Would suggest keeping the cat's nails trimmed so they are not as sharp.  Repairing leather will be harder, since you almost need something to wipe on and fill the tiny holes.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get to the underside of the holes, straighten out the fabric and put a very small drop of superglue on it, use a toothpick. If it's an armrest, you can try the superglue but try to push up the fabric to reduce the indentation. After the glue dries, touch up the area with a Magic Marker or felt tip marker after matching the color.

I have found that these repairs are noticeable in different lighting situations and have, in many instances, left the holes as is. If you have cats, you'll have holes.. that's just the way it is. Get a few scratch pads for them and place them near the furniture.